# Dimiss View Controller to Specific View Controller Issue

Tags: swift, dismissviewcontroller

i have VC1 and i present VC2 and then multiple VC's after it like in a flow,

```
VC3 -> VC4 -> VC5
```

Now i want VC5 to dismiss to `VC2`, i have searched and tried code and call the view controller by name but it isn't working fine, can anyone let me know how i can get this flow and dismiss to specific view controller?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unwindSegues to "go back" one or more steps in your navigation hierarchy.

Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

Comment: What if i want to use dismiss view controller. @Subramanian Mariappan

Comment: That is what unwind segue will let you do. Dismiss the current view controller and step back to any of the other view controllers in the navigation stack.

Comment: How can i call unwind segue at the result of my API? .@Subramanian Mariappan

Comment: I'm presenting view controllers and need to dismiss the view controller rather then to pop. @Subramanian Mariappan

Comment: In your api result, you can call performSegue function of viewController with your unwind segue identifier.

Comment: Brother, i have one issue VC2 is in another STORYBOARD and VC5 is another now how i can connect unwind Segue on it. @Subramanian Mariappan

Comment: Brother i have used unwind segue, but as i tap my button screen get dismiss and API is still in call. How can i dismiss when API result get called?. @Subramanian Mariappan

Comment: You should call the performSegue function on the api call result ( may be a completion block or something ) not on the button action.

Answer (score 0):

```
  let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController]
  self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 3], animated: true)
```

Note: here 3 indicates no of controllers

Comment: I'm presenting view controllers and need to dismiss the view controller rather then to pop. @Madhuri Doppalapudi